# Javascript- do somthing onclick any <a> tag except href="#" and href="<javascript>" tags

Tags: javascript, html

How to do something `onclick` any `<a>` tag except `href="#"` and `href="javascript"` tags

I have a script but it also working on `href="#"` like tags. I want to exclude `href="#"` and `href="javascript"` tags.

this is my current script

```js
    window.addEventListener('load', function (){
           if (!document.getElementsByTagName) return;
                var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
                for (var i=0; i<anchors.length; i++){
                     var anchor = anchors[i];
                     if(anchor.getAttribute("href"))
                          anchor.target = "_blank";
                }  

    function tabunder() {
      window.location = 'https://example.com' ;
     }  
       
       
    for (var i=0; i<anchors.length; i++){
     anchors[i].onclick = tabunder;
    }


    });
```

Comment: use with diff `class name` expect `a tag` and apply the click function into that `classnames` not with `a tag`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add if statement like below:

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
  var anchor = anchors[i], t = anchor.getAttribute("href");
  if (t){
    if(t === "#" || t === ""){continue;}
    anchor.target = "_blank";
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.  what can i do for for tabunder function. also it need to exclude href="#"

Comment: to register eventListener do it after:

anchor.target = "_blank";
anchor.onclick = tabunder;

no need to re-loop again